# PHP multiple scripts/requests

Tags: ajax, apache

we have the system like the following:

[image]

- **Client**: A regular client
- **P Server**: An apache server which basically runs like a proxy (forwards queries to M Server)
- **M Server**: Main server. All the work is done here.

and

Query `Q1` is not equal to query `Q1'` because **P Server** adds some more variables (like server time, client IP) Q1 before sending it to **M Server**.

Response R1 doesn't change at all. It is forwarded to client without changing.

Same applies for Q2.

The problem is, if ajax requests with `Q1` and `Q2` are sent at the same time, `Q2` waits in **P Server** for `R1` to finish.

So this is basically a PHP/Apache problem. But, I don't know how to dig this problem. Is it multiple php script problem or multiple request problem? 
I tried `session_write_close()` but that didn't change anything.

Comment: How are you running PHP (HTTPD or PHP-FPM)? How many processes are you spawning? Short answer is, Q1 should not wait for Q2 unless they're waiting on same resource.

Comment: it's httpd. What do you mean by same resource? Q1 and Q2 are sent to same file: `data_manager.php` and Q1` and Q2` are sent to same java servlet.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's default session handler is file based and uses exclusive locks. Which means the request related to the same session will be serialised. Actually this is a positive thing, it can avoid lots of strange parallel programming issues, race conditions/etc.

You can change the session handler to something less paranoid if you prefer. Or you can write an own file based one, without exclusive file locking to avoid this behaviour. Anyway be careful when accessing critical resources... (semaphores, locking, etc can be your friends.)

There are a few related comments here:

- [php blocking when calling the same file concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174378/php-blocking-when-calling-the-same-file-concurrently)
- http://00f.net/2011/01/19/thoughts-on-php-sessions/

You can verify this behaviour with `inotifywatch` on your session's directory. (Formerly inotify things could cause kernel panics and other strange behaviours... test it only on a test server...)